# Evitar que una pestaña se abra mas de una vez

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo una aplicacion con pestañas, pero me pasa algo, no puedo evitar que la pestaña se abra mas de dos veces, el codigo que uso para abrir las pestañas es este:

```
private void Nomina()
    {
        RH.frmNomina frmN = new RH.frmNomina();
        ELTabPage tab = new ELTabPage();
        tab.Text = frmN.Text;            
        tab.CaptionTextStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        tab.CaptionTextStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        tab.CaptionImageStyle.Image = Properties.Resources.icons8_nómina_50;
        tab.CaptionImageStyle.ImageSize = new Size(25, 25);            
        elTab1.TabPages.Add(tab);
        frmN.TopLevel = false;
        frmN.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmN.Parent = tab;
        elTab1.SelectedTabPage = tab;
        frmN.Show();
    }
```

lo que hago es abrir formularios en pestañas, pero no he encontrado la forma para evitar que no se abra otra repetida si ya tengo una abierta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer que el tab este como propiedad del formulario y cuando lo intentes agregar checas  si es null para poder crearlo y agregarlo si no entonces le podrías hacer un focus al que ya esta creado o lo que desee tu lógica.
el codigo quedaria mas o menos asi:

```
private ELTabPage tab;
private void Nomina()
    {
        RH.frmNomina frmN = new RH.frmNomina();
        //Aqui checo si ya existe la instancia del tab,
        //si existe selecciono el tab o simplemente me saldría del método con un return
        If(tab!=null)
        {
         elTab1.SelectedTabPage = tab;
         //otra lógica necesaria
         return;
        }
        //Al llegar aqui se entiende que aun no existía una instancia del tab, 
        //asi que se creara y agregara
        tab = new ELTabPage();
        tab.Text = frmN.Text;            
        tab.CaptionTextStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        tab.CaptionTextStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        tab.CaptionImageStyle.Image = Properties.Resources.icons8_nómina_50;
        tab.CaptionImageStyle.ImageSize = new Size(25, 25);            
        elTab1.TabPages.Add(tab);
        frmN.TopLevel = false;
        frmN.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmN.Parent = tab;
        elTab1.SelectedTabPage = tab;
        frmN.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Me funciono muy bien, gracias